# Stopped MySql with Disk Full - Cannot restart

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, mysql-5.6

I made the mistake of shutting down my mysql server (gracefully) with a full disk. It won't let me restart. There are no binary logs to remove - only data files as far as i can tell. what is aria_log.0000001 ? Can I remove an entire database directory - restart and then recover that db from backups once I've freed up enough space?

Comment: Aria is a MariaDB specific engine. But you tagged the question with mysql-5.6?

Have you freed up some space? What error are you getting?

Comment: service mysql start
 * /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /data/mysql is too full! -- i probably tagged it wrong?  No have not freed up space. Unsure how to do that. Can I delete an entire db directory full of .MYI, MYD, .frm files? restart the db and then recover that db from backups? Or will that make recovery impossible.

Comment: You can't restore a single database from backups, at least not if you have any InnoDB tables. You need to move the data directory to a bigger disk before you can do anything else.

Comment: You can't restore a single database from backups, at least not if you have any InnoDB tables. You need to move the data directory to a bigger disk before you can do anything else.

Comment: we have several databases that are myisam only. -- bigger disk is not an option. i do have some disk space available on another drive -- can I tell mysql to use two data directories? can i just delete the entire data directory and restore entire thing from backups?

Comment: If your backups are done right, yes, you can restore it to an otherwise blank machine. You can move a whole database directory to another drive and symlink it back. You may need to add `symbolic-links=1` to your my.cnf in the mysqld section.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to remove a singular very large myisam table (all files) .frm, .MYI, .MYD to free up disk space.  Then the `service mysql start` worked. Mysql did not seem to care about the table being missing.  Fortunately the one I deleted was a copy of a table. And on restart only 2 tables marked as crashed, one of which was a table being constructed at time of build. No big loss. Not the best scenario but could have been much worse.